# Spring Boot Test: How To Use Only Certain Beans?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-test

I have Spring boot applications with bunch of beans. From day to day their amount increase. So all the time I need to mock new beans or tests will fail. So, the question is quite simple: **how to force spring boot tests use only few certain beans from application context rather than all**?

Comment: First things first. Is is a unit test or an integration test. What are you trying to test?

Comment: Spring boot unit tests

Comment: Can you show which annotations you are using? You are most probably using annotations for running integration tests (`@SpringBootTest`) which you definitely should not do

Comment: indeed, @SpringBootTest

Answer (score 4):

So, I figure it out: you need to create class in test package and point test class to run spring from there and you have to define what package need to be scanned for components. For this purpose use prefix `scanBasePackages` or annotation `@ComponentScan`("packageForScan")

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.domain.folder1.package1","com.domain.folder1.package2"})
    public static class CustomApplicationRunner {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(CustomApplicationRunner.class, args);
        }
    }
```

And in test class you have to point for this class as a main class for running app.

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyTestClass.CustomApplicationRunner.class)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class MyTestClass {//tests}
```

This is how you can include or exclude(with annotation @ComponentScan) any packages from adding to application context.

Comment: A good example and explanation of this technique is described here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing